# Javascript setting cookie

Tags: javascript

It is said that setting cookie through javascript doesn't travel through the **HTTP header**.What could be the reason behind this?Why javascript cookie dont travel through **HTTP header**?

```
document.cookie ='ppkcookie1=testcookie';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies set by Javascript are sent in the HTTP header, but not at the time when you set the cookie. It will be included in the header the next time you make a request to the server.

Comment: But a link [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/http-headers-for-dummies/) says it wont travel through http header and is non-HTTP method

Comment: @Maizere: The article is talking about the `set-cookie` header which is used by the server to tell the browser to set a cookie. When you set it using Javascript it's set directly in the browser, so it will be sent in the `cookie` header to inform the server about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you fix the syntax error (the string literal <del>is</del> was, until the question was edited, missing its closing `'`), then it does (although, obviously, not until the *next* HTTP request is made).

Comment: But a link [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/http-headers-for-dummies/) says it wont travel through http header and is non-HTTP method

Comment: That is discussing the `Set-Cookie` response header, not the `Cookie` request header. If you set a cookie with JavaScript instead of HTTP then the HTTP header setting the cookie won't be used. That doesn't change what the browser does with cookies (i.e. send them back to the server in each request) one they have been set.